# Text on line within a line style QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, line, style

I'd like to create a line style in QGIS 3.4 where short text is written on the line. I am able to create a symbol layer in the line style, as a character symbol, but here only a single character is allowed.

Labelling is not an option for me, because the text is not an attribute of the line layer and text should be written several times on the line.

What I could create:

[image]

What I would like to create:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write multiple characters in the font marker using the "data defined override" editor. Click the `epsilon` near the list of characters, then `edit` and enter the desired text within single quotes.

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can get the desire outcome using labels.

You would type a static text within single quotes, put the label on the line and repeat it every 10 millimeters (or else). Then you would put a buffer around the labels to "break" the line. At last you can customize the color / bold etc.

If not all lines in the layer should be labeled the same way, you can use the rule based labeling to select / label them.

[image]

[image]